# ¿Como se puede hacer para generar un correlativo en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito ayuda para poder generar un correlativo igual a la imagen, cuando el promedio sea igual que el correlativo sea el mismo pero sin perder el sentido de la enumeración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este correlativo lo puedes obtener directamente usando la función `RANK`:

```
SELECT User, 
       Promedio, 
       Enumeracion,
       RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Enumeracion) Correlativo
FROM dbo.TuTabla
;
```

Comment: Claro pero cuando los promedios son iguales deseo que el correlativo también sea igual al anterior como en la imagen mostrada.

Comment: @kevin sí, y eso hace este código, lo revisaste?

Comment: Gracias, lo había intentado con Row_Number() y no me mostraba el resultado esperado, pero con el Rank() si se muestra todo correcto.